# Get all records from a table along with a selected record in single MySQL query statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pretty bad when it comes to designing database queries, can I have some help?

Here are the 2 tables (samples):

```
TABLE user: id, name, relationship_type_id
TABLE relationship_type: relationship_type_id (fk), relationship, contributing
```

Now, I want to use a single query to get:

1. All the `relationship_type` table's records (i.e. `SELECT * FROM relationship_type`)
2. And the specific `relationship` of the user who has `id = 5`

So the result is something like this (assuming table `relationship_type` has only 2 records)

```
"data": [
        {
            "relationship": "Friend" // for user id = 5
        },
        {
            "relationship_type_id": "1"
            "relationship": "Partner"
        },
        {
            "relationship_type_id": "2"
            "relationship": "Friend"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: SELECT columns FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON columnA = columnB [WHERE other conditions]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user.id, user.name
FROM user
LEFT JOIN relationship_type
ON user.relationship_type_id=relationship_type.relationship_type_id WHERE user.id=5;
```

Comment: Oops, it lists everything.

Comment: off course it is simple query to fetch record from two tables put you conditions and customize it.  just use user.relationship_type_id=relationship_type.relationship_type_id where and put condition the data will be filter.

Comment: Is there anyway I could list everything in table relationship_type as well?

Comment: relationship_type.relationship add column after column user.name with comma separated you will get you desired column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     rt.*, u.*
FROM 
     relationship_type rt
  LEFT JOIN 
     user u
    ON rt.relationship_type_id = u.relationship_type_id
WHERE 
     u.id = 5
UNION
SELECT *
FROM relationship_type;
```

Comment: It's close. Is there anything I could list everything within table relationship_type as well?